# Assembly, can't tell what is wrong with my code ARM processor

Tags: arrays, assembly, arm, reverse

```
.global reverse

.data
start: .word 1
end: .word 1
loopcount: .word 0

reverse:     
   ldr r3, =end
   str r1, [r3]    

next:
    ldr r3,=end
    ldr r2,=start
    ldr r3, [r3]
    ldr r2, [r2]

    cmp r2,r3
    bgt done
    cmp r2,r3
    beq done

    sub r3,r2
    mov r2,#0
    mov r1,#0

loop:
    cmp r2,r3
    beq next2

    add r2, r2, #1
    add r1, r1, #4
    b loop

next2:
    ldr r3, [r0]
    add r0, r0, r1
    ldr r2, [r0]
    str r3, [r0]
    sub r0, r0, r1
    str r2, [r0]

    add r0, r0, #4
    ldr r3,=end
    ldr r1, [r3]
    sub r1, r1, #1
    str r1, [r3]
    ldr r3,=start
    ldr r1, [r3]
    add r1, r1, #1
    str r1, [r3]
    b next


done:
    bx lr
```

I am trying to reverse an array and this is my reverse function in assembly, the function is reverse(int data*,size); data is an array and size is the size.  It works any array of size 5 but for longer arrays, for example of size 10, it will ignore the last 2 and act as if the array is of size 8 and swap it all as if the last 2 numbers in the array didn't exist, it would return:

```
Array:
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
My Return:
8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 9 10
```

I can't seem to find out what my issue is.

Comment: I can't seem to find why your code even sometimes work, as it looks very complicated to me, plus all the memory variables. But the debugger can show you what it does. I would start with arrays of size 0, 1, 2, ... I think there should happen something unexpected sooner than at size 10. (and don't look at output only, take a look per single instruction step, what is really happening .. sometimes you can get correct output even when the code doesn't work as you write it, just by lucky accident)

Answer (score 0):

Below is a crude and likely inefficient example of a reverse copy of one array to another; which may not be necessarily what you want but may foster some ideas.

Hardware        : Marvell Armada 370/XP 
model name      : ARMv7 Processor rev 2 (v7l)

```
.bss
        rArray: .zero
.data
        Array:  .word 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,32, 64, 128, 256, 512
        .equ    len.Array,.-Array
.text
        .global main
main:
        ldr r1,=Array                   // Array
        mov r2, #len.Array              // length of array
        mov r3, #0                      // zero init counter Array

        ldr r4,=rArray                  // rArray
        sub r5,r2, #4                   // rArray counter - 1 element

        1:
                ldr r10, [r1,r3]        // load word size element position x from Array
                str r10, [r4,r5]        // store word size element position x from Array into word size position y in rArray
        add r3, r3, #4                  // inc Array counter by 4 since word size is 4 bytes
        subs r5, r5, #4                 // decement rArray counter by 4 & get status (s)
        bpl 1b                          // branch back to loop if positive or zero; i.e., N condition flag is clear
```

Results using GDB:

```
(gdb) x/21d $r1
0x1102d:        1       2       3       4
0x1103d:        5       6       7       8
0x1104d:        9       10      11      12
0x1105d:        13      14      15      16
0x1106d:        32      64      128     256
0x1107d:        512
(gdb) x/21d $r4
0x11082:        512     256     128     64
0x11092:        32      16      15      14
0x110a2:        13      12      11      10
0x110b2:        9       8       7       6
0x110c2:        5       4       3       2
0x110d2:        1
```